# COMBINED SUMIFS and COUNTIFS is it possible?

Tags: countif, sumifs

I need to use combined sumifs and countifs on a single cell to get the absenteeism of the agent for a specific date.

is it possible to use division inside a sumifs formula to get the percentage?

[image]

formula for getting the absenteeism is Total Hours Spent / Total Hours Scheduled.

[image]

Comment: could you please explain a bit more or show the formula you tried. or just share a dummy google sheets page with the data

Answer (score 0):

Best way for these type of calculations will be to use **Pivot**

```
=SUMIFS(C1/D1,'AGENT_NAME','DATE')
```